# mathematica help ~ assign each element in a matrix to a value from a column vector

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have this 4x4 square matrix A, which has a random value in each element. I now have a column matrix (16x1) B which also has random values. The number of values in B is 16 which corresponds to the total number of elements in A.

I am trying to assign the values in B to elements in matrix A in the following way:

```
A[[1,1]] = B[[1]],
A[[1,2]] = B[[2]],
A[[1,3]] = B[[3]],
A[[1,4]] = B[[4]],
A[[2,1]] = B[[5]],
A[[2,2]] = B[[6]],
A[[2,3]] = B[[7]],
A[[2,4]] = B[[8]],
```

etc...

Does anyone know a convenient way of doing this so that I can achieve this for any NxN square matrix, and any length M column matrix(Mx1 matrix)? Assuming of course that the total # of elements are the same in both matrices.

Comment: I am guessing that "etc..." means p = Partition[B, 4];A = {p[[1]], p[[3]], p[[2]], p[[4]]}; but for arbitrary N I need more information.

Comment: hmmm, so What I'm hoping to do is have the first element in B replace the element (1,1) in matrix A, where first number is row and second number is column. I would like to do this for every element in B. I hope that clarifies things. Also thanks for the response, as you can probably tell I am new to mathematica.

Comment: Being new to Mathematica isn't a strike against you. But there are many many ways I could put 16 pigeons into 16 holes and I don't know what you have in mind. I was guessing, from your example before the etc... that what I wrote might be what you wanted and now I am thinking that maybe I was wrong. Perhaps you are actually looking for A=Partition[B,Sqrt[Length[B]]] Try that and see if it is what you are looking for. Note that "N" is reserved and defined by Mathematica to mean something very different, as are some other capital letter names. Watch out for that or you will get confusing answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mathematica 9, the function `ArrayReshape` can turn your list `B` into an arbitrary m x n Matrix.